# How do orbital elements change when force is applied orthogonal to the velocity vector?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, soi

Let's say you are standing on the Moon, with the Earth directly above your head (the moon being [tidally locked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) with the earth. At this point you and the Moon are sharing an orbit, both experiencing the same orbital elements.

You climb into a cannon that has just enough force for you to reach escape velocity (or, maybe more appropriately, leave the Moon's sphere of influence). Pull the trigger, and force is applied orthogonal to your velocity vector.

How does your new orbit differ from the Moon's? What orbital elements changed in this process? Would your orbital period relative to the moon decrease?

**UPDATE**

These answers are all really great, but I made things too complicated by involving the moon. Instead, more simply, how do orbital elements change when force is applied orthogonal to the velocity vector of an orbiting mass? Think about a satellite in GSO.

Comment: A nit, but you don't have quite the orbital elements of the Moon.  In fact your trajectory is not an orbit.  You are one lunar radius from the center of the Moon, and you are rotating counter to the orbital motion of the Moon to keep you looking straight up at Earth.  So your path is quite close to an orbit whose semi-major axis is one lunar radius less than the Moon's semi-major axis, but the period of your path is that of the Moon's.  Your "orbit" doesn't match your orbit period.  Your path is not an orbit.

Comment: The title of the thread asks a rather different question than does the question itself. I suggest re-asking the question raised in the title. Get rid of the Moon. It's a complicating factor. Ask instead what happens when an orbiting spacecraft fires orthogonal to its velocity vector.

Comment: I agree. The question became more complicated then intended, but the answers were creative enough that I really enjoyed reading the answers.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of updating this one.

Comment: The new question is very different from the original one. Now I am regretting investing time and energy running an n-body sim. It's also vague -- there are a multitude of directions orthogonal to the velocity vector. I'll assume you mean straight down. And what is the shape of the orbit? I'll assume you mean circular. It would change the flight path angle. The new perigee would be less than 180 degrees ahead. It would also increase the semi-major axis and the period some, depending on how much force is applied.

Comment: Ah sorry if it is vague. Don't be upset about running the n-body sim, it was very cool and I am sure by practicing it you became more experienced with it. Doesn't seem like a total loss. It helped me understand WHY my question was misleading, so very helpful in that sense. By "orthogonal to velocity vector" I meant the Centripetal force vector. I thought it was OK to use them interchangeably. I see now that it is more confusing than anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would your orbital period relative to the moon decrease?

Somewhat surprisingly, yes. You will end up in a slightly smaller orbit about the Earth with a slightly smaller period. That's assuming that (1) a patched conic is a valid approach (it probably isn't in this case), and (2) I've done my math right.

I'll assume the Moon is in a circular orbit at 384500 km, moving at 1.022 km/s relative to the Earth. I'll assume you fire the canon at the sub-Earth point at a velocity of 2.375 km/s, aiming straight towards the Earth.

Using a patched conic approximation, you are on a radial parabolic trajectory. It will take [1.315 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%282%29%2F3%29%2a%28sqrt%28%2866000+km%29%5E3%2F%284902.8000+km%5E3%2Fs%5E2%29%29+-+sqrt%28%281784+km%29%5E3%2F%284902.8000+km%5E3%2Fs%5E2%29%29%29) or [0.04814 sidereal months](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281.3153445+days%29%2F%2827.321661+days%29) to reach a distance of 66000 km from the center of the Moon (that's the radius of Moon's sphere of influence; c.f. the 60000 km radius of the Moon's Hill sphere), at which point that initial 2.375 km/s velocity will have dropped to [0.3854 km/s](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%2a%284902.8000+km%5E3%2Fs%5E2%29%2F%2866000+km%29%29).

Converting to geocentric coordinates, you will be [322100 km](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28384500+km%29%5E2+-+2%2a%28384500+km%29%2a%2866000+km%29%2acos%282%2api%2a0.04814292%29+%2B+%2866000+km%29%5E2%29) from the center of the Earth and moving at a speed of [1.195 km/s](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28%281.022+km%2Fs%29%2acos%282%2api%2a0.04814292%29%29%5E2+%2B+%28%281.022+km%2Fs%29%2asin%282%2api%2a0.04814292%29+%2B+%280.3854474+km%2Fs%29%29%5E2%29) relative to the Earth.

Using the vis-viva equation, this means you will be in an elliptical orbit about the Earth with a semi-major axis of [380700 km](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282%2F%28322097+km%29+-+%281.195+km%2Fs%29%5E2%2F%28398600.4418+km%5E3%2Fs%5E2%29%29). That orbit has a period of [27.056 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2api%2asqrt%28%28380700+km%29%5E3%2F%28398600.4418+km%5E3%2Fs%5E2%29%29).

You won't stay in that orbit for long. The Moon is going to perturb that orbit, big time.

Comment: +1 I didn't do maths (lack of time) but are you sure that the orbital period changes much? Otherwise, it sounds about right, you'd increase eccentricity and decrease periapsis at one end and increase apoapsis at the other. It should have a significant precession tho, I imagine it would eventually settle in a [rosette orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(orbit)) around Earth with translunar apoapsis?

Comment: Nevermind, didn't see all the links to WolframAlpha. Indeed, it's rather surprising. :)

Comment: Yes, it is surprising. My initial guess was that the period would increase because firing the cannon adds energy. The Moon steals most of that energy as the projectile drops Earthward. Note that if the Moon wasn't there, firing orthogonally at 2.38 km/s to a circular orbit at 384500 km would result in a hyperbolic trajectory. Earth escape velocity at that distance is only 1.44 km/s.

Comment: My initial guess was that it doesn't change the orbital period / semi-major axis and merely increases orbital eccentricity, since the new vector towards the focus is orthogonal to the orbital velocity vector (so non-canceling). It does add energy, but also makes the projectile come closer to Earth's SOI, so I assumed those more or less cancel each other out... eventually. Now I wonder how many orbits till it hits the Moon again... If (when) I'll find the time, I'll fire up GMAT and  see what it comes out with. Should be fun. :))

Comment: That boosting orthogonally to a circular orbit doesn't change the orbital period / semi-major axis by much at all is a reasonable approximation if Δv/v is much less than 1. Here, Δv/v is 2.38. That approximation doesn't hold in this case.

Comment: Good call, yes, you're absolutely spot on there.

Comment: My original intuition was incorrect. That original intuition was based on assuming that the energy and angular momentum of the projectile are conserved quantities. While they are conserved quantities in the two body problem, that is no longer the case in the three body (or n-body) problem. Total energy and angular momentum are of course conserved, but individual body energy and angular momentum are not.

Comment: I numerically integrated it, and you are correct, the specific energy of projectile relative to the Earth on the first orbit is less than that of the Moon.  After that, the Moon can make it go up or down.

Comment: In fact, in one case I got it to escape the Earth-Moon system.

Comment: Orbital energy of a single object in the 3 body scenario can vary. So semi-major axis isn't invariant. [Jacobi quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_integral) is the invariant for an object in a 3 body scenario.

Comment: @MarkAdler - Re *In fact, in one case I got it to escape the Earth-Moon system* -- Hence the last line of my answer, "You won't stay in that orbit for long. The Moon is going to perturb that orbit, big time."

Comment: Yes, that there would be dramatic changes in the orbit (e.g. eccentricity and orientation) was obvious to me, but that there would be dramatic changes in energy was not.  Now what is obvious to me has been notably updated, especially seeing that you can even escape.

Comment: This response is incorrect. Patched conics are a poor approximation. As shown elsewhere on this thread, tiny differences in velocity can make big differences in orbits. But in general, you won't get a semi-major axis of 380,700 km nor a 27.056 day period.

Comment: @HopDavid - I could say the same about your answer. Yours too is incorrect. It is subject to significant numerical inaccuracies. My answer is pretty close, and I did qualify the dubious applicability of the patched conic approach in my lead paragraph. I certainly overstated the accuracy. This answer is correct in a qualitative sense in that the osculating semi-major axis from a very high quality simulation is less than that of the Moon's orbit. This result goes counter to (incorrect) intuitive thinking that the period will increase.

Comment: At escape velocity the semi major axis wouldn't be slightly less, it'd be substantially less, more in the neighborhoold of 300,000 kilometers with a period of 20 days. But just slight variations in velocity make big changes in orbits. This is what's indicated by my sims. Initially both you and Mark Adler gave wrong answers. Then Mark changed his answer using 3 body sims. Now his results are similar to mine. Yes, there are some numerical inaccuracies in my sim. But your answer is way off.

Comment: @HopDavid - My simulation (and it's a very good sim; it uses a massively verified tool) gives an osculating semi-major axis of 377,220 km at the moment the projectile exits the Moon's SOI. That 380,700 km figure is not that far off from that simulated value. The SMA decreases after that, but not to 300,000. As far as "giving wrong answers", look at the edit history. This was my only answer, and it hasn't changed much at all.

Comment: Yes, your one and only answer was wrong and it remains wrong. However Mark Adler's answer changed substantially. Like you, he was thinking 2-body mechanics. Then he saw his error corrected his answer. When the projectile reaches EML1 it is **not** in an elliptical orbit. But let's assume it is. At EML1, r is about 327000 km. Plug this r and your a into the vis viva equation and you get a velocity 1.18 km/s. Minimum apogee is 426,000 km, well beyond the moon. Now look at Adler's sims. Like my sims his projectiles fall to a lower altitude perigee rather than rising to a higher apogee.

Comment: Measure the ellipses in Adler's illustrations. Most have a semi-major axis of around 300,000 km. His -.0981 has an perigee of around 100,000 km and an apogee of about 300,000 km. The apogees and perigees of his ellipses are pretty similar to mine. So your massively verified tool seems to be contradicting his results as well as mine.

Answer (score 4):

"Your new orbit" isn't simply a two-body orbit about the Earth that you might be thinking of, since the Moon is still there after you (barely) escape.  In the long term it will be a complicated trajectory that will eventually result in you impacting the Moon, escaping the Earth-Moon system, or possibly even impacting the Earth.  So the concept of orbital elements is not terribly useful.

However, you can imagine an effective orbital period when you are orbiting the Earth but are far from the Moon.  That is related to your total specific energy, where if that is less than the Moon's, your orbital period is less than the Moon's, and vice-versa.

Here are some examples of your trajectory where you are launched at or a little above the lunar escape velocity.  (The gray circle is the Moon's orbit.  The blue disk in the middle is the Earth to-scale.)

Shown under each trajectory is your specific energy in the Earth-Moon system.  You can see that initially it is always less than the Moon's (the gray line), and so your "orbital period" is shorter than the Moon's.  But it can go above the Moon's after a few lunar flybys, and usually does.  Where the plot doesn't go all the way across, it impacted the Moon where it ended.  In one case, you can see that you escape the Earth-Moon system completely.

[image: plots of trajectories and specific energy]

Here are some interesting borderline cases.  Below 0.978 they all do the same thing -- immediately reimpact.

[image: plots of borderline cases]

Comment: Try a few runs with slightly less than escape velocity -- e.g., 99% of escape velocity (-0.99 times escape per the titles of your graphs), maybe even down to 98.5% of escape velocity. Much less than that and the projectile just falls back toward the Moon.

Comment: Yes, I did those and it behaves much the same down around $-0.99$.  I've also run them around $+1$, where the code automatically starts instead at the far point of the Moon and shoots straight up.

Comment: Try lower even lower. Things get weird when the projectile has barely enough energy to escape the Moon's SOI (~66000 km).

Comment: To leave the moon's sphere of influence it suffices to get the apolune close to EML1. From the moon's near point straight up, that takes about 98% escape velocity.

Comment: I don't trust the results too low, since I don't have detection of impact in the code.  I did run cases there and lower still, and they are quite wonky.  (Technical term.)  However there were probably impacts with the Moon.  I might look at putting in such detection ...

Comment: Heh these are even cooler than I expected, the specific energy graphs are all over the place with such small changes to initial velocity. What's the mass of the projectile, have you tried launching on different dates and is the software you're using top secret (one of those you need to apply for and then NASA kindly tells you you're not a US citizen and it's off limits LOL), or can we have a link please? :)

Comment: Indeed, I manually detected an impact for 0.979 times escape velocity.

Comment: @TildalWave: I am running idealized, not real-world cases with the Moon in a perfectly circular orbit and the Earth fixed at the barycenter.  All this complexity exists in the idealized case.  It's just a few lines of Mathematica code.  The projectile mass does not enter into the equation.

Comment: I implemented impact detection and added some interesting borderline cases.  Also I updated the first plot, since I didn't realize before that it impacted.

Comment: That's about where I get impacts, at about 98% of escape velocity. Give it just enough velocity so that just barely escapes and you should get a rather eccentric orbit about the Earth. Until the projectile and Moon come close to one another, that is.

Comment: For my model I used Horizon ephemeris to grab position and velocity vectors at 6 different times. My model includes the sun as well as earth and moon. I started at a full moon, then advanced 1/6 of a lunar sidereal day. Nudging particles from EML2 at a full or new moon can fling them past sun-earth L1 or L2 and out of the earth's sphere of influence. Doing the same nudge from a half moon will have the pellet returning to earth.

Comment: I get impacts in less than $10^7$ seconds at lots of values between $0.98$ and $1$.  E.g. $0.992$.  If I went longer, I'd get more, even above $1$.

Comment: @MarkAdler - Those collisions might just be an artifact of how you are doing the integration. Try using extended precision, and try using different integrators. These borderline cases are stiff problems, with stiffness being transient. Numerical precision will suffer if you do all your integration in the Earth-Moon barycenter frame. It's best to switch between a selenocentric and geocentric frame when the object crosses the Moon's SOI. (I sicced a graduate intern on a very similar problem several years ago.)

Comment: The example for $0.992$ does exactly the same thing, including impacting, with 60 digits of precision and other time integration methods.  So it is not a numerical artifact, aside from the numbers I happened to use for the physical parameters.  However the whole thing is an artificial example, so it doesn't mean much except for observing general behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[image: 3 body sim]

Here's a screen capture from an orbital sim for a variety of pellets launched straight up from the moon's near point. The red #1 pellet is just under escape velocity. The blue #11 is a hair over. Tidalwave, The blue dot is the earth. The white orbit is the moon. I placed darker colored pellets at EML1, EML2 as well as EML4 and EML5.

The rainbow pellets are from what I call orbital shotgun. The pellets velocity and direction vary from one extreme (pellet one) to another (Pellet 11). Here is the page I used to do this sim: [Orbital Shotgun](http://clowder.net/hop/railroad/emlShotGun.php) Making smaller time increments makes the model more accurate but slower. I had to make time increments pretty small for this sim. It can be seen that pellet 1 doesn't quite make it past EML1 and falls back to the moon. The rest of the pellets escape the moon's sphere of influence and fall into earth centric orbits

In general pellets the pellets will hit the earth, moon, or be completely ejected. Just a tiny variation in velocity can make a huge difference in outcome. In this diagram the fastest pellet varies from the slowest by .6 meters/second:
[image]